# Hub inheritance in Signalr in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-2

I'm using signalR to build a real-time website.
I have 2 hub:

- **NotificationHubCore**
- **NotificationHub (inherits NotificationHubCore)**

My solution includes 2 small projects : **Domain** & **Web**.
I put **NotificationHubCore in Domain**, **NotificationHub in Web**.

Now, in the web section, I want to acess NotificationHubCore by using :

```
 GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHubCore>();
```

It always returns null to me.

**My question is : how can I access to NotificationHubCore through NotificationHub.**

I've tried:

```
var notificationHub = new NotificationHub();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(NotificationHubCore), () => notificationHub);
```

But that way didn't work.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You may use SQL Server to distribute messages across a SignalR application that is deployed in two separate applications.

Create a new database for the backplane to use. You can give the database any name. You don’t need to create any tables in the database; the backplane will create the necessary tables.

Refer this article and section "Scaleout with SQL Server" for further details - [why SignalR](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/why-signalr/)